# How do I Specify the Correct Back-End URL for SignalR 3.0 When I have Two Projects in my Solution? Currently Getting 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Getting this error in my SignalR project:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404,
```

... fired some time after I invoke `connection.start()`

After succeeding with [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio), I modified it use two projects in a single solution, a back-end and a front-end.

- Back-end is a .NET Core Web API project
- Front-end is .NET Core Web Application

In the back-end startup.cs file, I attempt to specify the URL using 'ChatHub', like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
});
```

I placed the code above in the Startup.cs file of my back-end project. Also added `services.AddSignalR();` in same file, in `ConfigureServices` method, per the tutorial.

I cut-and-pasted my Hub code from the tutorial.

Besides the error message above, the debugger further indicates:

- `Information: Normalizing '/chatHub' to 'https://localhost:44365/chatHub'`
- `Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server`

I literally cut-and-pasted the JavaScript for my front-end, note the URL shown below on line 2, which should match the endpoint above:

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This code throws the error listed above. I tried some variations on the URL, including https://localhost:44365/BackEnd/ChatHub. No luck.

Then I tried splitting my solution and running each project separately. Revised my JavaScript to use the back-end port, like this:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("https://localhost:44384/chatHub")
    .build();
```

But when I examined the browser, it indicated

```
Information: Normalizing '/chatHub' to 'https://localhost:*44365*/chatHub'.
```

Note the port it used is the wrong port, it is the port for the front-end.

### Summary

I believe I took a working tutorial and modified it only by splitting it into two projects, but I can't figure-out the URL to connect to my back-end. I tried variations on the URL, for some reason it didn't use the correct port when I split-out the back-end project from my original solution

[image: Screen shot shows JavaScript errors in console]

Answer (score 3):

> After succeeding with this tutorial, I modified it use two projects in a single solution, a back-end and a front-end.

To connect to Hub server from a separate SignalR JavaScript client application, you can refer to the following steps and code snippet.

*Allow cross-origin SignalR connections in your Hub Server application (Back-end, a .NET Core Web API project).*

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44365")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
});
```

*Specify Url to the hub on JavaScript client, like below.*

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44384/chatHub").build();
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fei Han, this looks promising. When I return from my road trip I'll try it, hopefully I can mark it as the answer then!

Comment: That got me going in the right direction, but wasn't quite enough to completely fix the situation. I managed to get it working by using what you suggested plus adding a Cors policy. Even that wasn't enough, you have to invoke app.UseCores, using the policy, _before_ invoking app.UseRouting(), which didn't appear in any documentation I read.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working by following Fei Han's suggestion plus adding a [named policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.0). Also, you must invoke UseCors in the correct sequence or you will get a frustrating error. Here is the pertinent code from Startup.cs in my back-end:

```
//This string is for the named policy, discussed in the link above:
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
   services.AddControllers();
   services.AddSignalR();
   services.AddCors(options =>
   {
       options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
       builder => {
           //URLs are from the front-end (note that they changed
           //since posting my original question due to scrapping
           //the original projects and starting over)
           builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44323", "http://localhost:51263")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowCredentials();
       });
   });
}
```

...

Still in Startup.cs, the following shows the all-important sequencing of UseCors/UseRouting:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    //Crucial: the next statement must precede UseRouting or you will get an error
    //"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control 
    //check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present 
    //on the requested resource."
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
    });
}
```

Comment: [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) says you have the ordering around the wrong way: "The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization"

Comment: The order and the specific origins did the trick for me. I'm using flutter with signalR_core package and I was having the same issue. Thank you so much.